Constrained optimization with heuristic algorithm in actual production
In a real production problem, if you decide to use a heuristic algorithm (such as GA), what are the mainstream methods to deal with constraints in constraint optimization?
I mean, I knew that there were ways of dealing with constraints, like Lagrange method, penalty function method, and I used them in my college study, but when I got to work, I found that most of the real production problems had more complex constraints than research, there are not that many assumptions to provide ideal conditions and I couldn't use these methods well to transform problems. It is also hard to find cases to study on the Internet (most of them solve too simple a problem).
So I would like to ask, in your many years of work, when dealing with actual production problems, if you consider using heuristic algorithms, what ways do you use to deal with constraints in the problem?

For genetic algorithms, there is a variant called random key genetic algorithms (and a variant of that called biased random key genetic algorithms -- the bias part being a tweak to the evolutionary rules). In a random key genetic algorithm, you pick a chromosome encoding (maybe a permutation of an integer sequence, maybe a binary or real vector) and devise a function that maps chromosomes to feasible solutions. The key is that the mapping function must guarantee feasibility. When you go to compute the objective value of a chromosome, you decode it using that function and feed the decoded solution to the original objective function.
For instance, in a bin packing problem I might assign index numbers (1, 2, ...) to the items to pack and use a permutation of those numbers as the chromosome. To decode a chromosome, I would take the items in the permuted order and stuff them into the first bin, skipping over items that don't fit, until it is no longer possible to fit an item into the bin. Then I would start over with remaining sequence (after removing packed items) and try to stuff them into the second bin, and so on. Assuming an unlimited supply of bins, this is guaranteed to eventually produce a feasible solution (meaning every item got packed).
Figuring out a decoding algorithm is obviously problem-specific. In cases where I cannot find a chromosome/decoder combination that guarantees feasibility, I might "cheat" and tweak the evolutionary rules to remove infeasible solutions from the population (evolutionary analog: they did not survive birth).

Thx for suggestions. But I still have some questions, like if a model has a constraint that can't be written as a chromosome by encoding/decoding, how do you usually handle it at such times, turn it into a penalty term or just kill the non-compliant individuals? I'm asking because the models I encounter for production problems usually have more than ten constraints, and I'm not confident that I can build a form of encoding and decoding that can be compatible with them all

On at least one occasion in the past I treated infeasible offspring as "stillborn" (and repeated crossover until I got a feasible offspring). Another possibility is a version of mutation, where you modify ("mutate") an infeasible offspring to make it feasible. I have considered the penalty approach, but if the penalty is sufficiently severe it is equivalent to deleting the infeasible solution. (A large enough penalty ensures it is not selected for crossover.)  I'm pretty sure both of these approaches are inferior to a decoding algorithm that converts all chromosomes to feasible solutions.

Thanks to your advice, by practicing these days I have completed my first genetic algorithm for solving real industrial problems. My last question is, what should I usually do to improve the performance of a heuristic algorithm after completing it? I did some simple tests and found that its convergence is not stable and it is still a bit slow

GAs are inherently random, so fluctuations in convergence speed are to be expected. They come with a significant number of parameters. The library I use in R lets you set population size, mutation and crossover probabilities, and the number of "elite" chromosomes to retain, plus you can design your own crossover and mutation operators. Experimenting with those parameters might help. You might also consider an "island" GA, in which the population is split into groups that do crossover separately, with occasional "migration" of chromosomes from one "island" to another.

Also, some GA libraries may allow you to add a component that takes a new "offspring" (after mutation) and tries to improve it by something like line search, local search or whatever. Finally, GAs make good use of parallel processing, so look for a library (or write your own GA code) with multiple threads in mind.

Besides the mentioned answer, there are many cases in which either a simple rule or an algorithm, or a heuristic can solve a practical problem in an efficient manner and still without defining any constraints.
For example, to solve a resource scheduling model when one would like to assign tasks to a resource and with the aim of minimizing the total compilation time of tasks, by using an LP/MIP/CP, you have to define some constraints to achive the optimal solution while by a simple rule called $\text{SPT}$ and actually without any complaint for defining constraints you can achive the same optimal solution.
